# How to change order of the specific object in react JS

Tags: arrays, reactjs, sorting, react-functional-component

I have buttons that are coming from API.

```
This is my buttons array output.

0: {uploaded: "User", id: 1, status: "A1"}
1: {uploaded: "User", id: 2, status: "A2"}
2: {uploaded: "User", id: 3, status: "A3"}
3: {uploaded: "User", id: 4, status: "A4"}
4: {uploaded: "User", id: 5, status: "A5"}
5: {uploaded: "User", id: 6, status: "A6"}



this is how I am mapping..

{buttons?.map((item) => (
    <Button
        outline
        key={item.id}
        disabled={isDisabled(item, status)}
        onClick={onTap.bind(null, item)}
        className={`statusName`}
    >
        {item.status}
    </Button>
))}
```

Now I have a requirement when status named **status: "A6"** is available in API response I need to show the order of my buttons as A1 A6 A2 A3 A4 A5 when  **status: "A6"**  not available in API response I need to show the order of my buttons as is not available A1 A2 A3 A4 A5. How I can change the order sorting based on **status: "A6"** value.

Comment: What does 'status: "A6" is available' mean?

Comment: I mean when it's available in API response

Comment: Do you mean, whether or not it's included in the response? Why not just sort your array, then search for the "A6" status and move that element in the array? Is the response data already sorted? Can you make your backend return the order you prefer?

Comment: find the item in the original array, then filter it out. then splice it to the index you want, is it not working for you for some reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if A6 is present and based on this use [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method to costruct new array

```
export default function App() {
  let data = [
    { uploaded: "User", id: 1, status: "A1" },
    { uploaded: "User", id: 2, status: "A2" },
    { uploaded: "User", id: 3, status: "A3" },
    { uploaded: "User", id: 4, status: "A4" },
    { uploaded: "User", id: 5, status: "A5" },
    { uploaded: "User", id: 6, status: "A6" }
  ];

  let a6Idx = data.findIndex((obj) => obj.status === "A6");
  let newData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
  if (a6Idx >= 0) {
    newData.splice(a6Idx);
    newData.splice(1, 0, data[a6Idx]);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {newData.map((obj, idx) => (
        <button key={obj.id}>{obj.status}</button>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-ives-3k00e)

Comment: i  fixed the hard-coded "5" with the index `a6Idx` to be 100% correct

Comment: Instead of two splices that remove (and shift) and insert (and shift) you can simply swap the elements at each index, something like `[data[a6Idx], data[1]] = [data[1], data[a6Idx]]`.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of ways you could approach this.
Is there a particular reason why `"A6"` still comes after `"A1"`?

My method is like so:

```
Array.prototype.move = function(from, to) {
    this.splice(to, 0, this.splice(from, 1)[0]);
};

var buttonArray = [
  {uploaded: "User", id: 1, status: "A1"},
  {uploaded: "User", id: 2, status: "A2"},
  {uploaded: "User", id: 3, status: "A3"},
  {uploaded: "User", id: 4, status: "A4"},
  {uploaded: "User", id: 5, status: "A5"},
  {uploaded: "User", id: 6, status: "A6"}
]

var a6Index = buttonArray .findIndex(item => item.status === "A6")

// Since Arrays are zero-indexed, move to 1
buttonArray.move(a6Index, 1)
// [
//   {uploaded: "User", id: 1, status: "A1"},
//   {uploaded: "User", id: 6, status: "A6"},
//   {uploaded: "User", id: 2, status: "A2"},
//   {uploaded: "User", id: 3, status: "A3"},
//   {uploaded: "User", id: 4, status: "A4"},
//   {uploaded: "User", id: 5, status: "A5"}
// ]
```

The nice part about this method is that if `"A6"` is not in your array, the array order will remain unchanged.

You can then map through your array as normal.

Comment: Thanks for the solution and your effort. but it's breaking my code.